# Accessing functions of different classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to update the value of a number, to make it 30, by accessing 3 different functions ( they have the same name ) from 3 different classes. Can you please help me ? I have to use the functions in class D. I tried with creating 3 different objects and applying to each of them the function, but it did not work

```
using namespace std;

int callA=0;
int callB=0;
int callC=0;
class A
{
protected:
   void func(int  & a)
   {
      a=a*2;
      callA++;
   }
};

class B
{
protected:
   void func(int & a)
   {
      a=a*3;
      callB++;
   }
};

class C
{
protected:
   void func(int & a)
   {
      a=a*5;
      callC++;
   }
};

class D 
{
    int val;
    public:
        //Initially val is 1
         D()
         {
            val=1;
         }

         //Implement this function
         void update_val(int new_val)
         {

          A a;
          B b;
          C c;
          c.func(b);
          b.func(a);


     }
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I need to access the function 3 times, firstly from A, then from B and then from C, in order to make the new_value = 30.

Comment: So, 1 *2, from the func of A; then 2*3 from B, and then 6*5, from C

Comment: It's a bit off topic, but I can't help but wonder how utterly pointless this homework is. I can't figure out what it's supposed to teach.

Comment: Problem 1: declare `func` as public. Problem 2: `func`wants an `int &` argument and you pass an 'A' and a 'B'  argument. But it's really unclear what this is supposed to do or what it is supposed to demonstrate.

Comment: You should pass `val` to all your `func` functions and not pass the other objects to each other. But should all those functions really be protected? Which part do you have to write and which part is set in stone?

Comment: I only have to write the update function, so yes, those functions should be protected

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to derive `D` from `A`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: @Mihaela could you post the exact text of your homework, including all requirements?

Comment: I was thinking the same as Karsten. Without deriving from those classes or adding friend declarations. Its impossible to call those functions.

Comment: @PaulRooney no one has read my answer 35 minutes ago?

Comment: @granmirupa the Op is saying the methods should be protected.

Comment: @PaulRooney In my answer there is a reference on how to derive a class. Or to use friend class.. So my answer cover all possible answers. Imho

Answer (score 1):

You can't access from the D class to the `func` method of A,B,C classes because they are protected.

For accede to protected method of a class your class should be a friend or a derived class.
Otherwise you need to set their visibility to public.

For more read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Using derived class, this should work;

```
using namespace std;

int callA=0;
int callB=0;
int callC=0;
class A
{
protected:
   void func(int  & a)
   {
      a=a*2;
      callA++;
   }
};

class B
{
protected:
   void func(int & a)
   {
      a=a*3;
      callB++;
   }
};

class C
{
protected:
   void func(int & a)
   {
      a=a*5;
      callC++;
   }
};

class D : public A, public B, public C
{
    int val;
    public:
        //Initially val is 1
         D()
         {
            val=1;
         }

         //Implement this function
         void update_val(int new_val)
         {
          // if new_val is '1'
          //now you can call func methods;
          A::func(new_val);
          B::func(new_val);
          C::func(new_val);
          // then if you print new_val it is '30'
          // c.func(b); // You can't pass b. b isn't an integer
          // b.func(a); // idem


     }
};
```

// ..... //

```
int main(){
    D d;
    d.update_val(1);
}
```

Comment: @MichaelWalz I aswered 40 minutes ago. In my answer there is a reference on how to derive a class. Or to use friend class.. So my answer cover all possible answers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz however now I update it, using multiple inheritance

Comment: OK, now it's a possible solution to a strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int callA=0;
int callB=0;
int callC=0;
class A
{
public:
   void func(int  & a)
   {
      a=a*2;
      callA++;
   }
};

class B
{
public:
   void func(int & a)
   {
      a=a*3;
      callB++;
   }
};

class C
{
public:
   void func(int & a)
   {
      a=a*5;
      callC++;
   }
};

class D 
{

    public:
         int val;
        //Initially val is 1
         D()
         {
            val=1;
         }

         //Implement this function
         void update_val()
         {

          A a;
          B b;
          C c;
          a.func(val);
          b.func(val);
          c.func(val);


     }
};

int main ()
{
    D d;
    d.update_val();
    std::cout<<d.val<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't meet the requirements of the OP: see his comment:  _I only have to write the update function, so yes, those functions should be protected_